# Logging and inheritance of loggers' configurations in Python

Tags: python, logging

I come from SLF4J and Log4J, so that might be the reason why I don't get how logging works in Python.

I have the following

---- logging.yaml

```
version: 1

handlers:

  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    stream: ext://sys.stderr
    formatter: simpleFormatter

  file:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    filename: app.log
    mode: w
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simpleFormatter

formatters:
  simpleFormatter:
    #class: !!python/name:logging.Formatter
    #class: logging.Formatter
    format: '%(name)s %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
    datefmt: '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'


root:
  level: INFO
  handlers: [console, file]

mod:
  level: DEBUG
```

----- mod.py

```
import logging

def foo ():
    log = logging.getLogger ( __name__ )
    log.debug ( 'Hello from the module' )
```

---- main.py

```
from logging.config import dictConfig
import yaml
with open ( 'logging.yaml' ) as flog:
    dictConfig ( yaml.load ( flog ) )

import logging

from mod import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':

    log = logging.getLogger ( __name__ )
    log.debug ( 'Hello from main' )

    foo ()
```

With the config above, I would expect to see only the message `'Hello from the module'`. Instead, nothing is printed. When I set `DEBUG` for the root logger, both messages are printed.

So, aren't the messages forwarded to the upper loggers? Isn't the `mod` logger a child of `root`? Doesn't the `mod` logger inherit the `handlers` configuration? (I've tried to repeat `handlers` in `mod`, but nothing changes).

How can I achieve a configuration saying: default level is `INFO`, the level for this module and sub-modules is `DEBUG`, everything goes to the handlers defined for `root`?

Comment: I'll just put this here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fairly simple error: note that, per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-dictschema), configuration for loggers *other than `root`* should be under the `loggers` key as:

> a dict in which each key is a logger name and each value is a dict
>   describing how to configure the corresponding Logger instance

Adding this key and indenting the appropriate lines, to give:

```yaml
loggers:
  mod:
    level: DEBUG
```

works as expected:

```bash
$ python main.py
mod 20/07/2016 14:35:32 DEBUG Hello from the module

$ cat app.log
mod 20/07/2016 14:35:32 DEBUG Hello from the module
```

Comment: I knew it was something silly! Thanks Jon, one thing to add is that root mustn't go under loggers.

Comment: @zakmck yes: again, *"other than root"*.